# Get key and value separately with array.map function - ReactJS - TypeScript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am doing my best to fetch my data separately and use it in my JSX, but it seems that I am doing something wrong.

As an example a retrieve from the BE an array that looks like this :

```
const myArr = [ 
   { 
    A: "Ananas", 
    B: "Banana", 
    C: "Citroen"
   }
]
```

And my ultimate goal is to map over it and use it into my JSX like this:

```
...
 <Select onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e)}>
    {myArr.map((key,value) => ( 
       <MenuItem key={key} value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>
    ))}
 </Select>
...
```

Behind the scenes I prefer to look something like this :

```
<MenuItem key="A" >Ananas</MenuItem>
<MenuItem key="B" >Banana</MenuItem>
<MenuItem key="C" >Citroen</MenuItem>
```

But it seems that somewhere along the way I got lost. If someone can give me a hand I would be very grateful. Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your array has only one item, and you want to iterate over its [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Also, you are misunderstanding the signature of the callback function in [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The first param is the element, and the second is the index. You do not need the index in your case.

```
 <Select onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e)}>
    {Object.entries(myArr[0]).map(([key,value]) => ( 
       <MenuItem key={key} value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>
    ))}
 </Select>
```

Comment: Works like a charm . Thanks mate !!! The only thing that i added was a conditional rendering validation , because my array is not defined at the launch . So i did `myArr[0] &&`

Comment: Is there a way to pass the `key` to the `Select` component . I do not want to put the select inside of the `.map()` , because it gives me a wrong render .

Answer (score -1):

If you would like it to look something like this

```
<MenuItem key="A" >Ananas</MenuItem>
<MenuItem key="B" >Banana</MenuItem>
<MenuItem key="C" >Citroen</MenuItem>
```

I would first rearrange the data (personal preference), so it'll be easier to map.
so my data would be something along the lines of

```
myArr = [
{"name": "A".
"value": "Ananas"},
{"name": "B",
"value": "Banana"},
{"name": "C",
"value": "Citroen"}
]
```

```
myArr.map(item => {
   return(
      <MenuItem key={item["name"]}>{item["value"]}</MenuItem>
   )
}
```

This is just my preferred easier method, though there might be other answers

Comment: Then you would hace the Select onChange as a parent element .:)

Comment: `As an example a retrieve from the BE an array that looks like this :` As i said from above this is the data that i recieve from the Back End i cannot change it , because this is the structure

Comment: Your answer is not correct even if i could change the structure